# Rails: image_tag helper / umlaut in file name throws error in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, utf-8, heroku, production

I am uploading an image with a file name containing an umlaut via [dragonfly](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly/) in a Rails 3 app on Heroku. Then I'm trying to display the image using

```
image_tag @model.image.url, …
```

In development everything works just fine, but in production I'm getting:

```
incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT
.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb:129:in `*'
```

After reading a bit I've added

```
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
```

in `environment.rb` but the problem remains.

*What is the proper way to go about this?* Do I have to fix the file name when uploading? I was under the impression this should work just fine in Rails 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could try something like `url.force_encoding('utf8')`

You could also simply sanitize the url in the model before saving it to the database - that's what I did. And, yes, I sometimes stumble over this in the weirdest places, too.

This is what my model looked like:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :sanitize_title

  private
  def sanitize_title
    self.title = self.title.force_encoding('UTF-8').downcase.gsub(/[ \-äöüß]/, ' ' => '_', '-' => '_', 'ä' => 'ae', 'ö' => 'oe', 'ü' => 'ue', 'ß' => 'ss').gsub(/[^a-z_]/,'')
  end
end
```

This will replace the German umlaute with their ASCII counterparts, convert spaces to underscores and drop everything else.
The first line `# encoding: UTF-8` is important or ruby will complain of non-ASCII characters in the model.rb file...

Comment: I ended up doing just this, but my implementation differs a bit (see my answer). Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Rhywden's answer, here my solution specific for Dragonfly:

```
image_accessor :image do :after_assign
  after_assign{|i| i.name = sanitize_filename(image.name) }
end

def sanitize_filename(filename)
  filename.strip.tap do |name|
    name.sub! /\A.*(\\|\/)/, ''
    name.gsub! /[^\w\.\-]/, '_'
  end
end
```

Details here http://markevans.github.com/dragonfly/file.Models.html and here  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#file-uploads .